# Flutter/Dart: Field 'futureAlbum' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

model_album.dart

```
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

http_controller.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:feed/models/model_album.dart';

class HttpController extends GetxController {

  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit;
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      debugPrint('futureAlbum initialized');
      return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}
```

view_http.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:feed/views/view_http.dart';
import 'package:feed/models/model_album.dart';
import 'package:feed/controllers/http_controller.dart';

class ViewHttp extends StatelessWidget {

  var httpController = HttpController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
      future: httpController.futureAlbum,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }

        // By default, show a loading spinner.
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

I am trying to learn how to use Getx and Network requests. I took this code from:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

I tried to modify to work with Getx and get error:
LateInitializationError: Field 'futureAlbum' has not been initialized.
I thought onInit method should have initialized when controller instantiated in view_http.dart file.  Thoughts?

Comment: late keyword-only use when you are sure that value is not null, so batter way to you can use `Future<Album?>? futureAlbum;`

Comment: Thanks. I added it and it is null and is not initialized in `onInit` method which is what I think it should do. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need futureAlbum in HttpController. Just delete that, and change the code from `httpController.futureAlbum` to `future: httpController.fetchAlbum`. The other option is, change your ViewHttp to StatefulWidget, then put the futureAlbum there

```
late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
late HttpController httpController;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit;
    httpController = HttpController();
    futureAlbum = httpController.fetchAlbum();
  }
```

Then in the future builder, use `future: futureAlbum`. Hope its help you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I tried changing `httpController.futureAlbum` to `future: httpController.fetchAlbum`.
I got error "The argument type 'Future<Album> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Album>?' "

I am trying to use only stateless widgets wtih Getx package handling state.

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean `future: httpController.fetchAlbum()`

Answer (score 0):

@Ananda is correct you do not need a separate variable of `futureAlbum`;

To add to that, when you initialize the object of a GetX class, you don't do this

```
  var httpController = HttpController();
```

You do this.

```
final httpController = Get.put(HttpController());
```

Or if you have already initialized somewhere else in the app you can find the same controller.

```
final httpController = Get.find<HttpController>();
```

When you call `Get.put(...())` thats when the `onInit` functions is called. But in your case you don't even need that. Your GetX class can just be this.

```
class HttpController extends GetxController {
  Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      debugPrint('futureAlbum initialized');
      return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}
```

And your `ViewHttp` can be like below. This will show your API data on screen.

```
class ViewHttp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final httpController = Get.put(HttpController());
    return Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
      future: httpController.fetchAlbum(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }

        // By default, show a loading spinner.
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Also as an FYI, while I do recommend GetX in general, it's not doing anything in your `HttpController` class. If that's all you plan on having that class do, then you can remove the GetX part, initialize it the way you were doing before and the functionality wouldn't change.

One of the main points of GetX (and most other state management solutions) is that you always access the same instance of the controller (unless you specifically need a new instance which usually you don't), and any data you store in that instances is easily accessible from anywhere in the app via `Get.find<...>()`. From there the `onInit()` becomes super handy and usually allows for all widgets to be stateless.

But as I said, if you're just doing a basic API all with that class, you don't need GetX there.